# Strange behaviour of onOptionsItemSelected

Tags: java, android

I've a problem with public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item).

My Code:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
{
    switch(item.getItemId())
    {
        case R.id.action_timetable:
        {
            wbViewTimetable.setInitialScale(200);
            loadTimetable();       
            break;              
        }
        case R.id.action_map_eg:
        {               
            wbViewTimetable.setInitialScale(100);
            wbViewTimetable.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/floor_plan_eg.png");
            break;
        }
        case R.id.action_map_og:
        {
            wbViewTimetable.setInitialScale(100);
            wbViewTimetable.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/floor_plan_og.png");
            break;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

My main.xml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" >


<item android:id="@+id/action_timetable" 
    android:title="Timetable"/>

<item android:id="@+id/action_map_eg" 
     android:title="Map 2" />

<item android:id="@+id/action_map_og" 
      android:title="Map 1"/>

<item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
      android:title="Settings" 
      android:orderInCategory="100"/>
```

So my problem is, that, if I choose a menu entry, every time another one will be choosen and opened, f.e. if I choose the first one the second one will be choosen, the second the third and so on.

The only one that realy works is the last (action_settings) one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see any obvious reason why this would be happening from the code you have provided, however your switch/case syntax is different.

You've written it like this:

```
switch(item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.action_timetable:
    {
        // ...
        break;
    }
    case R.id.action_map_eg:
    {
        // ...
        break;
    }
}
return true;
```

Mine is written like this:

```
switch(item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.action_timetable:
        // ...
        return true;
    case R.id.action_map_eg:
        // ...
        return true;
}
```

It seems unlikely, but this could be the source of the problem. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! Anyhow this and cleaning my project afterwards solved my problem.